# Vue.js - rendering initial products as HTML with Laravel

Tags: laravel, vue.js

I'm using Laravel and Vue to show products for a shop. The initial products are loaded through Laravel and sent to the view, and then they are fed to the vue script as initial data. This data is then used to render the page at load. After this, when changing a filter, vue gets the new data async from the server and changes the products. It all works fine.

But I would like to be able to render the initial products without Javascript for SEO-purposes. The only idea I got, is:

- Render initial products with a Laravel Blade foreach-loop
- Don't feed any initial data to vue
- When new content should be loaded, remove this initial PHP-rendered data and activate the v-for loop.

But it's not the prettiest solution. Any ideas on how to make this better?

Comment: for SEO it's best you use SSR or Pre-rendering. given you have an initial blade template look into `inline` templating in vue check this [link](https://medium.com/js-dojo/7-ways-to-define-a-component-template-in-vuejs-c04e0c72900d#42b3)

Answer (score 0):

You need to achieve SSR (server-side rendering) for your APP.
Some options described here - https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/ssr.html